# passing reading from ina219 to a file

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I would like to use ina219 to log current and voltage to a CSV file,
the python program should be running in infinte loop until we press ctrl+c

this is what I tried

```
def read():
    ina = INA219(SHUNT_OHMS)
    ina.configure()
    try:
        with open('loop.csv','w') as f1:
            writer=csv.writer(f1, delimiter='\t',lineterminator='\n',)
            row = '%.3f' % ina.voltage()+'\t'+'%.3f' % ina.current()+'\t'+'%.3f' % ina.power()+'\t'+'%.3f' % ina.shunt_voltage()
            writer.writerow(row)
    except DeviceRangeError as e:
        # Current out of device range with specified shunt resistor
        print(e)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open('loop.csv','w') as f1:
            writer=csv.writer(f1, delimiter='\t',lineterminator='\n',)
            row = 'Bus Voltage V'+'\t'+'Bus Current mA'+'\t'+'Power mW'+'\t'+'shunt_voltage mV'
            writer.writerow(row)
    while 1 :
        read()
        time.sleep(.300)
```

this is what I expect it to get from loop.csv

```
Bus Voltage V   Bus Current mA   Power mw   Shunt voltage mv
2               3                1          2
```

but this is what I got

```
2   .   7   6   4   "   "   -   0   .   0   9   8   "   "   0   .   4   8   8   "   "   -   0   .   0   1   0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't put "\n" after you read the file .   you only use "\t"